# JSON conversion using JOLT with ARRAY - remove $id

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

someone can me help? I'm new to jolt. Can you please tell me how can i trasform the below json message with array based upon the position in to the below output json message using jolt.

My JSON is:

```json
{
  "rotas": [
    {
      "$id": "49122583",
      "nomeRota": "BRAGANÇA PAULISTA",
      "placa": "EVQ6280",
      "nomeMotorista": "MARCO ANTONIO",
      "dataSaida": "2022-05-02T07:00:00-03:00",
      "dataChegada": "2022-05-02T13:23:09.6-03:00",
      "tipoVeiculo": "VUC",
      "documentoTransportadora": "52912748000679",
      "codigoTransportadora": "52912748000679",
      "custoFrete": 0,
      "metrosDistanciaTotal": 88005,
      "metrosDistanciaRetorno": 14522,
      "segundosRetorno": 818,
      "codigoRota": 3930798,
      "numeroRota": 1,
      "exportado": true,
      "dataExportacao": "2022-04-29T11:08:47.44-03:00",
      "atividades": []
    }
  ]
}
```

.......

How do I formulate my ''jolt''?

output JSON :

```json
{
  "rotas": [
    {
      "nomeRota": "BRAGANÇA PAULISTA",
      "placa": "EVQ6280",
      "nomeMotorista": "MARCO ANTONIO",
      "dataSaida": "2022-05-02T07:00:00-03:00",
      "dataChegada": "2022-05-02T13:23:09.6-03:00",
      "tipoVeiculo": "VUC",
      "documentoTransportadora": "52912748000679",
      "codigoTransportadora": "52912748000679",
      "custoFrete": 0,
      "metrosDistanciaTotal": 88005,
      "metrosDistanciaRetorno": 14522,
      "segundosRetorno": 818,
      "codigoRota": 3930798,
      "numeroRota": 1,
      "exportado": true,
      "dataExportacao": "2022-04-29T11:08:47.44-03:00",
      "atividades": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to remove the $id of rotas

Thankss

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***remove*** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "rotas": {
        "*": { //indices of the "rotas" array
          "$id": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]